# ArrayList vs Vector - does this illustrate difference in synchronization?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I'm trying to understand the difference in behaviour of an ArrayList and a Vector. Does the following snippet in any way illustrate the difference in synchronization ? The output for the ArrayList (f1) is unpredictable while the output for the Vector (f2) is predictable. I think it may just be luck that f2 has predictable output because modifying f2 slightly to get the thread to sleep for even a ms (f3) causes an empty vector ! What's causing that ?

```
public class D implements Runnable {
   ArrayList<Integer> al;
   Vector<Integer> vl;

   public D(ArrayList al_, Vector vl_) {
      al = al_;
      vl = vl_;
   }

   public void run() {
      if (al.size() < 20)
         f1();
      else
         f2();
   } // 1

   public void f1() {
      if (al.size() == 0)
         al.add(0);
      else
         al.add(al.get(al.size() - 1) + 1);
   }

   public void f2() {
      if (vl.size() == 0)
         vl.add(0);
      else
         vl.add(vl.get(vl.size() - 1) + 1);
   }

   public void f3() {
      if (vl.size() == 0) {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            vl.add(0);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
      } else {
         vl.add(vl.get(vl.size() - 1) + 1);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String... args) {
      Vector<Integer> vl = new Vector<Integer>(20);
      ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
      for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++) {
         new Thread(new D(al, vl), Integer.toString(i)).start();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: For future reference: While I appreciate the space conservative approach, readability sorely suffers as a consequence.

Comment: It's been edited. I wasn't quick enough to even edit my own question !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question: Yes vector is synchronized, this means that concurrent actions on the data structure itself won't lead to unexpected behavior (e.g. NullPointerExceptions or something). Hence calls like `size()` are perfectly safe with a `Vector` in concurrent situations, but not with an `ArrayList` (note if there are only read accesses ArrayLists are safe too, we get into problems as soon as at least one thread writes to the datastructure, e.g. add/remove)

The problem is, that this low level synchronization is basically completely useless and your code already demonstrates this.

```
if (al.size() == 0)
   al.add(0);
else
   al.add(al.get(al.size() - 1) + 1);
```

What you want here is to add a number to your datastructure depending on the current size (ie if N threads execute this, in the end we'd want the list to contain the numbers `[0..N)`). Sadly that does not work:

Assume that 2 threads execute this code sample concurrently on an empty list/vector. The following timeline is quite possible:

```
T1: size() # go to true branch of if
T2: size() # alas we again take the true branch.
T1: add(0)
T2: add(0) # ouch
```

Both execute `size()` and get back the value 0. They then go into the true branch of the and both add `0` to the datastructure. That's *not* what you want.

Hence you'll have to synchronize in your business logic anyhow to make sure that `size()` and `add()` are executed atomically. Hence the synchronization of vector is quite useless in almost any scenario (contrary to some claims on modern JVMs the performance hit of an uncontended lock is completely negligible though, but the Collections API is much nicer so why not use it)

Comment: Yes but why does f3 output an empty vector ? That's the question.

Comment: @Raj You're not even calling f3 anywhere in your code? Also there's no output anywhere either. Apart from the slight chance of some exceptions in the ArrayList code the general race condition is the same for both programs. Although in practice the locking, etc. may change observable behavior - that's obviously implementation (and luck) dependent.

Comment: Replace the call to f2 with a call to f3. From the original question: "modifying f2 slightly to get the thread to sleep for even a ms (f3)". I understand that the race condition exists for both. I'll look at it some more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Raj Ah ok. Well the sleep only makes the race condition more obvious. Basically the sleep "guarantees" (not by the spec but in practice) that another thread is scheduled which then leads to the demonstrated problem. Without the sleep it's extremely unlikely that a thread is preempted exactly between executing `size` and `add`. If you ran it long enough it would probably happen sooner or later though. Could take a day, a week or 10ms though - that's the biggest problem with race conditions ;)

Answer (score 0):

In The Beginning (Java 1.0) there was the "synchronized vector".

Which entailed a potentially *HUGE* performance hit.

Hence the addition of "ArrayList" and friends in Java 1.2 onwards.

Your code illustrates the rationale for making vectors synchronized in the first place.  But it's simply unnecessary most of the time, and better done in other ways most of the rest of the time.

IMHO...

PS:
An interesting link:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/523384/java/java/ArrayList-Vector-size-incrementation

Comment: You're lucky I don't have enough reputation to down vote this answer. It's not relevant at all.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are Thread safe. ArrayLists are not. That is why ArrayList is faster than the vector.
The below link has nice info about this.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-06/03-qa-0622-vector.html

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to understand the difference in behaviour of an ArrayList
>   and a Vector

`Vector` is `synchronized` while `ArrayList` is not. `ArrayList` is not thread-safe.

> Does the following snippet in any way illustrate the difference in
>   synchronization ?

No difference since only `Vector` is `sunchronized`